# Output javascript variable inside HTML content

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/ and come across this function:

```
function hello(msg) {
        BootstrapDialog.show({
            title: 'Button Hotkey',
            message: $('<textarea id="try" class="form-control">//how do I output msg variable here?</textarea>')
        });
    }
```

Now the msg variable is loaded correctly (tested using `alert(msg)`) but I don't know how to to include that value to be output inside the `<textarea>msg?</textarea>` tag

Comment: you want to show the modal in textarea? as text

Comment: `'<textarea>' + msg + '</textarea>'`, no?

Comment: Too obvious. And at ES6 you can use templates, such as... \`${msg}\`

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question correctly,'msg' variable can be printed in the Textarea by adding it to the HTML template string as follows,

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
        title: 'Button Hotkey',
        message: $('<textarea id="try" class="form-control">'+ msg +'</textarea>')
    });
```